# How to send requestparameter in POST request using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, http-post

I need to send a POST request to a URL and send some request parameters. I am using HttpURLConnectionAPI for this. But my problem is I do not get any request parameter in the servlet. Although I see that the params are present in the request body, when I print the request body using request.getReader. Following is the client side code. Can any body please specify if this is correct way to send request parameters in POST request?

```
String urlstr = "http://serverAddress/webappname/TestServlet";

String params = "&paramname=paramvalue";

URL url = new URL(urlstr);

HttpURLConnection urlconn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

urlconn.setDoInput(true);

urlconn.setDoOutput(true);

urlconn.setRequestMethod("POST");

urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");

urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(params.getBytes().length));

urlconn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

OutputStream os = urlconn.getOutputStream();

BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

writer.write(params);

writer.close();

os.close();
```

Comment: Not sure if you need that leading & in your params string. Also, you should writer.write(params.getBytes())

Answer (score 2):

To be cleaner, you can encode to send the values.

```
String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

URL url = new URL("http://yourserver.com/whatever");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kal said, get rid of the leading `&` and don't bother with the BufferedWriter. This works for me:

```
byte[] bytes = parameters.getBytes("UTF-8");
httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytes.length));
httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpUrlConnection.connect();
outputStream = httpUrlConnection.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(bytes);
```